# ActiveMQ Classic queue attribute name equivalents in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We recently migrated from ActiveMQ Classic to ActiveMQ Artemis. We are using Telegraf to collect Artemis metrics to InfluxDB.

We have previously created Grafana dashboards for ActiveMQ Classic metrics which are not working for Artemis because of the difference in attribute names.

I think the only attribute name that didn't change for us was `ConsumerCount` all the others have changed. After some research we have been able to find and "translate" other attributes as well.

But there are a few that we cannot find an equivalent for. Like `MinEnqueueTime`, `MaxEnqueueTime`, `AverageEnqueueTime` and `AverageMessageSize` for example.

Is there any documentation on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis is not a complete re-implementation of ActiveMQ Classic. Therefore, there is not necessarily a 1-to-1 correlation between things like metrics names or MBean attributes. In this case there is no corresponding values for these metrics because there has not yet been a compelling reason to implement them.